# Rcpp could not accept POSIXlt arguments

Tags: rcpp

When a vector of Datetime with the format of POSIXlt is passed into a function in Rcpp, it could not handle it! However, if you change the vector into as.POSIXct it works perfectly. Does anyone has an explanation for this problem?
Respects.

Comment: Please don't spam this site. This is basically the same as your previous question.

Comment: I am very surprised when I hear "spam"! Considering my level of R and Rcpp they are different questions!

Comment: `POSIXlt` is a "wide" type, broken-out into components. You cannot insert that into, say, a `data.frame` either. So `POSIXct` it is -- as that is just a (fractional double) number.